# Using order by count in left joined tables

Tags: sql, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I'm having problem with sorting my query results by the count field. My simplified query:

```
$customers = Doctrine_Core::getTable("Customer")->createQuery("c")
    ->leftJoin("c.Project p")
    ->orderBy("COUNT(p.id) ASC");
    ->execute();
```

I am pretty sure that the problem isn't doctrine related. The ORM-generated query retrieved from the application logs selects only one row, and it contains a line:

```
ORDER BY COUNT( r2.id ) ASC
```

After removing which all rows are selected properly.

The `ORDER BY` clause causes the query to select only one row from the customers table. I think it has something to do with the customers not having any projects assigned to them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the rest of the ORM-generated query to the question? Ordering by an aggregated value is something that can only be done on grouped queries - if you want to order by p.id (rather than a count of p.id) then you should change your query to be `ORDER BY  r2.id ASC`.

Comment: No, I want it to be ordered by the related rows count.

Comment: Does 'no' mean that you are unable to add the rest of the ORM-generated query to the question?

Comment: No, no, it was about the ordering by ids. I'll attach the rest of the query later because I don't have access to the application right now.

Comment: Also, is this MySQL? (I suspect that this form of query would fail in most other RDBMSs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to group by the number of Projects for a Customer, try using a GROUP BY clause and aggregate on the primary key of Customer:

```
$customers = Doctrine_Core::getTable("Customer")->createQuery("c")
->select('c.*, count(p.id) as count')
->leftJoin("c.Project p")
->groupBy('c.id') // or the primary key of Customer
->orderBy("count ASC")
->execute();
```